# spring-cloud-stream kafka consumer concurrency

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

With spring-cloud-stream's kafka binder, how do you configure concurrent message consumers (in a single consumer jvm)? If I understand correctly, having concurrent message consumption when using kafka requires partitions, but the [s-c-s docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.RELEASE/reference/html/_configuration_options.html) indicate that to use partitioning you need to specify partition selection in the producer via partitionKeyExpression or partitionKeyExtractorClass. Kafka docs mention round-robin partitioning.

The s-c-s docs don't mention spring.cloud.stream.bindings.*.concurrency at all, though that does seem to matter in the use case I've described above. With producer config

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        customer-save:
          destination: customer-save
          group: customer-save
          content-type: application/json
          partitionCount: 3
```

and consumer config

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        customer-save: 
          destination: customer-save
          group: customer-save
          content-type: application/x-java-object;type=foo.Customer
          partitioned: true
          concurrency: 3
```

I seem to be getting the behavior I want (at least somewhat). I can see that there are 3 consumer threads active sometimes, though there does seem to be some partitioning other than round robin at play, since some messages seem to wait for a busy consumer thread and get consumed once that thread is finished. I'd assume that's because the message is getting sent to the same partition.

Is there some default key extraction and partitioning strategy that's getting used on the producer when I don't specify partitionKeyExpression or partitionKeyExtractorClass? Is this an appropriate way to set up an s-c-s consumer with kafka where you want multiple threads consuming messages in order to increase consumer throughput?

Answer (score 7):

Since your producer is not partitioned (there is no `partitionKeyExpression` set), the producer side will round robin over the 3 partitions (if that is not the observed behaviour, please open a ticket in Git Hub). If you configured a `partitionKeyExpression` then the producer will effectively partition the data according to the configured logic.

On the consumer side, we ensure thread/partition affinity because this is a widely-respected Kafka convention - we ensure that messages on a given partition are processed in order - which might account for the behaviour you are observing. 
If sending messages A,B,C,D to partitions 0,1,2,0 - D will have to wait until A is processed, even if there are two other threads available.

One option for increasing throughput is to overpartition (which is a fairly typical strategy in Kafka). This would spread out messages even further and would increase the chance that messages are sent to different threads.

The other option for you to increase throughput if you don't care about ordering would be to process messages asynchronously downstream: e.g. by bridging the input channel to an ExecutorChannel.

Generally speaking, `partitioned` refers to the ability of a client to receive partitioned data (Kafka clients are always partitioned, but this setting also applies to Rabbit and/or Redis). It is used in conjunction with the properties `instanceIndex` and `instanceCount` to ensure that the partitions of a topic are divided correctly between multiple application instances (also see http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_instance_index_and_instance_count)

Comment: Wouldn't bridging to an ExecutorChannel with kafka result in dropped messages when a consumer fails to process the message? The current kafka message id for the single consumer would be incremented as soon as the listener container passed the request to the executor channel.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question - yes, that would be possible. We do support the `spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.default.autoCommitEnabled=false` property to suppress autocommits, case in which an `Acknowledgment` header is provided to the inbound message, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/support/KafkaHeaders.java#L38 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/listener/Acknowledgment.java'.

Comment: Even in that case, though, it is possible that if messages are processed in the reverse order, for a later message to acknowledge an offset for an earlier one.

Comment: In summary, for increasing throughput and ensuring reliable processing, the suggestion is to increase the number of partitions and the number of consumers, either by increasing concurrency or by using multiple application instances.

Comment: One thing to verify is that there are actually 3 partitions being created on the topic. If they are not, please file an issue. We are currently making some fixes to the property management system, largely to simplify the configuration process, so this could be something that we need to address.

Comment: I just tested and with kafka 0.8.2.2 when the producer starts only 1 partition is created. After the consumer starts, 3 partitions are present. I'm checking this via kafka-topics.sh --describe

Comment: Thanks. This is an issue - as I suspected, the `partitionCount` value is effective only if partitioning is configured. We will fix this for RC1, but in the mean time, I would suggest using `spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.default.minPartitionCount=3` (or more) to increase the number of target partitions. You should observe the expected behaviour.

Comment: Another option with similar effect is to use the `nextModuleCount` and `nextModuleConcurrency` properties of the binding (instructing the producer to create partitions accordingly).

Comment: On s-c-s 1.0.0.RC2 now, and it appears you need spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.minPartitionCount on the producer and spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.{topic}.consumer.minPartitionCount on the consumer to get a consistent partition count set up on the topic, depending on which creates the topic. Why doesn't the consumer use spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.minPartitionCount? The partition/concurrency config is all over the place.